# How can I connect docker private IP from outside container

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I have created a local spark cluster on docker compose with bind port.

For master node, I can connect to its Web UI in browser by localhost:8080

and 3 worker nodes 1,2,3 by localhost:8081,localhost:8082,localhost:8083.

[image]

As you can see these 3 worker node were given private address(192.168.224.3~5).

Then if I click the link in worker ID column. it will redirect to 192.168.224.3:8081, 192.168.224.4:8082, 192.168.224.5:8083 and return "This site can’t be reached".

All I can do is to manully modify these address to localhost:8081~8083 and refresh with no issue.

Is there a way I can connect to these private IP address outside the docker container or is Spark can make these link to something like localhost:8081~8083?

Comment: The Docker-internal IP addresses are mostly useless and you can't reach them (unless you're very specifically on the same host, it's a native Linux host, and you're directly using Docker Engine without Docker Desktop or another VM-based solution).

Answer (score 0):

If you choose docker network as `host`, you will be able to access the worker nodse with machine's IP address and respective ports